# Need a word that means taking a tradition and changing it for the worse

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes what a corporation is doing when it takes a long standing tradition of a business and then changes it so that it becomes cheap and no longer represents what it once stood for. Sort of like the concept of selling out.

Comment: So, a corporation changes its business model. Are you looking for a word that suggests illegality, or just a change in reputation for the quality of goods or services?

Comment: @KannE - Get this -- they now have Birkenstock knock-offs.

Comment: The company has now *spoiled* or *tainted* Halloween.

Answer (score 2):

The corporation ***perverted*** the long standing practises of the business they took over.

per·vert·ed
/pərˈvərdəd/

(of a thing) having been corrupted or distorted from its original course, meaning, or state.

> this sudden surge of perverted patriotism

---

[source](https://www.google.com/search?q=perverted+meaning)

Answer (score 0):

The word **Corrupted** can be applied to changes in a religion, language or culture over time:

> to alter (a language, text, etc.) for the worse; debase.

Source: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/corrupted

Example usage from the Introduction to Theoretical Linguistics. Cambridge University Press. p. 42. ISBN 978-0-521-09510-5.

> "The traditional grammarian tended to assume [...] that it was his
>   task, as a grammarian, to 'preserve' this form of language from
>   'corruption'."

Comment: "Debase" itself could also be an option.